# Maven Build Process Gets Terminated Without Any Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-3

**Hello Team,**

I am running a Maven Build (mvn clean install) on my system where the Maven Build is getting terminated after the below line without any error.

```
[INFO] Compiling 231 source files to C:\Users\abc\git\ebiz-utils-lib\target\classes
```

I am using the latest maven version 3.6.3 (with hardware configuration - Intel i5 4th Generation Processor and 16 GB RAM).

Below are the commands which I am using to perform maven build of the project.

**In IntelliJ:**

D:\Software\jdk-11.0.10+9\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\abc\git\ebiz-utils-lib -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=300m -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dmaven.home=D:\ebiz_new\maven\apache-maven -Dclassworlds.conf=D:\ebiz_new\maven\apache-maven\bin\m2.conf "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=60635:C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\ebiz_new\maven\apache-maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;D:\ebiz_new\maven\apache-maven\boot\plexus-classworlds.license org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.3.2 --update-snapshots -X -e clean install

**In Local Terminal:**
mvn clean install

I have tried several solutions but nothing worked for this issue.

The same issue persists in the IDE and in the console as well.

I downloaded the new maven distributable also but that even didn't work for me.

I have added screenshots herewith for your perusal.

Edit: I have also observed that java.exe process gets terminated during the build process for maven (may be due to high CPU utilization as the CPU utilization percentage moves into range of 80% - 100%), but there is no way by which I can confirm the exact issue.

Request you to provide some solution for this issue.

Thanks.

[image: Error in IntelliJ]

[image: Error in Local Terminal]

Comment: Why are you using so much options like `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` and `-Xmx4096m`? Furthermore have you tested on plain command not from within the terminal of the IDe ... ? Why are you using `install` and not `verify` ?

Comment: These options are necessary as I am operating behind a corporate proxy which requires a secure SSL connection (so used it to bypass it) and for the second option was just added to avoid out-of-memory error as there are so many classes maven has to compile.

The reason why I am using install is that I want that artifact to be installed in the local repository. Also even if I try simple command mvn clean verify from command prompt outside the IDE, the same issue is there.

Comment: 4 GiB RAM for compiling? How many class do you have? I doubt that it is related .... Just try to run without tests `mvn clean verify -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X` on plain command line ... (redirect into a file the log output)...

Comment: @khmarbaise Please read my comment above. The output is same even if I am running ```mvn clean verify -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X``` on plain command line. I have also observed that java.exe process gets terminated during the build process may be due to high CPU utilization, but there is no way by which I can confirm the exact issue.

Comment: Are you running a virus scanner ? My assumption is that based on the change of files etc. the virus scanner is being triggered and produces the problem..

Comment: Yes, but I cannot disable the antivirus as it is being managed by IT administrator of the organization, also it doesn't show any warnings or logs for threats/malicious programs detected in logs which I can show to the IT administrator and ask for disabling it temporarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause of this issue.

The issue was the system files on the hard drive were corrupt causing malfunctioning of the system, and the reason for the corruption of system files was the Hard Drive on the system was failing i.e. it had too many bad sectors.

Thus, replaced the new hard drive in the system and reinstalled the operating system, and did all the required setup.

The issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same problem but I just tried different jdk that intelliJ Idea already suggest to download i.e. [Amazon Corretto version 8](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-8-ug/downloads-list.html) then I got any error and so process finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**Run in the same problem while migrating project from JAVA 8 to JAVA 11, upgrading jacoco-plugin from 0.8.1 to 0.8.4 did the job.
Analysing maven dependencies, seeing from where jacoco is pulled and then fixing the version should solve the issue**